# How to get JSON string from knockout object with dynamic observable properties?

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, typescript

**Variable Declaration using typescript**

```
variableName: any;
```

**Constructor**

```
constructor(private _data?: IInterface) {
    if (_data) {            
    this.variableName = this.tokoObservable(_data.variableName); 
    }
}
```

**tokoObservable FN**

```
private tokoObservable(data: string): ko.Observable<any> {
    let obj = data? JSON.parse(data) : { };
    let output = ko.observable<any>({});

    for (let prop in obj) {
        output[prop] = ko.observable<any>(obj[prop]);            
    } 

    return output;
}
```

**Explanation**

This code creates observable properties and places them into the variableName.

The properties are observable so when I change the content they do get updated.

The problem comes when I want to see the JSON of the whole object.

```
ko.toJSON(variableName)
```

returns an empty {}

However

```
ko.toJSON(variableName.propertyName())
```

returns the value of the property.

What I want is to return the JSON string of the entire object

```
{"propertyName": "propertyValue}
```

Comment: I've never used Typescript, but it looks like your `tokoObservable` returns an observable object with observable properties. Would it help to call `ko.toJSON(variableName())` ?

Comment: what if you do ko.toJS(variableName), and then stringify the result to JSON?

Comment: Please extend the code just a wee bit until it's an [mcve]. Seems like there's only a few bits (i.e. some test data and bootstrapping) needed for that?

Comment: A screenshot of `console.info(data)` would be quite useful too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I changed that enabled it to work.

```
private tokoObservable(data: string): any {
    let obj = data? JSON.parse(data) : {};
    let output = {};

    for (let prop in obj) {
        output[prop] = ko.observable<any>(obj[prop]);            
    } 

    return output;
}
```